# Proving $\sum_{r=n+1}^{2n}(3r+4) =\frac n2(9n+11)$ (mathematical Induction)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

Hope someone can help me understand what to apply here, currently stuck.
I know you are meant to do summation. However I try to find to solve problems like this and I'm not finding much resources.

$$\sum_{r=n+1}^{2n}(3r+4) =\frac n2(9n+11)$$

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): "*Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts..*"

Comment: Do you really need to prove it *by induction*? A direct proof would be easier, imo (applying to $m=2n$ and $m=n$ the fact that $\sum_{r=1}^m(\color{blue}4r+\color{green}3)=\color{blue}4\frac{m(m+1)}2+\color{green}3m$).

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant $\sum_{r=1}^m(\color{blue}3r+\color{green}4)=\color{blue}3\frac{m(m+1)}2+\color{green}4m.$

Comment: All i know is that it should be done by summation

Comment: You need to understand what the summation is trying to denote here. You need to find $3(k +1 + k+2+k+3+\cdots + 2k) $, which is an arithmetic progression. Similarly, $4$ is added $2k-(k+1)+1$ times.

Comment: Such a question has been [asked and answered many times on this site](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3Dn%2B1%7D%5E%7B2n%7D(3k%2B4)%24&p=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find:

$$\sum_{n=k+1}^{2k} 3n+4 $$
The number of terms in this sum is $2k-(k+1)+1 = k$.
So the sum is $$ 3(k+1 + k+2 + k+3 + \cdots + 2k) + 4(k) \\ = 3(\underbrace{k + k + k  \cdots + k)}_{k \ times} + 3(1+2+\cdots + k) +4k $$
Consider the sequence $1+2+\cdots + k$.

Now note that $k+1=(k-1)+2=(k-2)+3=\cdots$, ie the sum of of the $n$th element from the left hand of the sequence and the $n$th element from the right hand is equal for all possible values of $n$. In total, this value is added $\frac{k}{2}$ times, since pairing is done in groups of $2$.

So the sum becomes:

$$3k^2 + \frac{3(k+1)(k)}{2} + 4k$$
$$\frac{k}{2}\cdot (6k+3k+3+8)$$
$$\frac{k}{2}\cdot (9k+11)$$

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Moreover, it was [a FAQ](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3Dn%2B1%7D%5E%7B2n%7D(3k%2B4)%24&p=1).

Comment: I understand. Will keep that in mind for future answers. Thanks!